# Как выровнять блоки относительно друг друга с разным количеством контента?

Tags: вёрстка, flexbox

При запуске кода один из заголовков занимает больше места. Как сделать как на картинке?

```css
.blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  max-width: 45%;
  min-width: 45%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block">
    <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum.</h1>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet excepturi commodi, minus quo enim, porro soluta voluptates officia nihil veritatis et eligendi. Provident libero adipisci dignissimos enim fugiat sunt? Architecto </div>
    <div class="text-bottom">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, magni quos sed reiciendis quam quasi! Ipsa architecto aliquam autem minus.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit aolor sit aolor sit aolor sit amet.</h1>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet excepturi commodi, minus quo enim, porro soluta voluptates officia nihil veritatis et eligendi. Provident libero adipisci dignissimos enim fugiat sunt? Architecto </div>
    <div class="text-bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat sint necessitatibus, voluptate distinctio omnis unde. Officia aliquid quod dolor quo.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Варианта три: 1) выравнивать скриптами; 2) использовать _table_ или _grid_; 3) задавать нужным блокам фиксированные размеры.

Comment: ну гвоздями так гвоздями

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2em 3em;
  width: 350px;
}

.item {
  border: 4px solid #22b14c;
  padding: .5em .75em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #22b14c;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">lorem</div>
  <div class="item">lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="item">lorem ipsum dolor<br>lorem ipsum dolor<br>lorem ipsum dolor<br>lorem ipsum dolor<br>lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="item">lorem ipsum dolor<br>lorem ipsum dolor<br>lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="item">lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="item">lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```